# How to iterate multipart file upload request.getParts() by for loop by index value

Tags: java, android, servlets

I am trying to upload files by multi part in android via servlets(server code). So i can iterate the loop like this.

```
for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
//uploading current part.. working..
}
```

but i want to iterate like below,

```
  for (int i = 0; i < request.getParts().size(); i++) {
    //request.getPart(i); not working..
   //request.getPart(i+1); not working..
    }
```

The reason is  need current part as well as next part on each and every iteration. Is it possible to do like above or any other ways to do it. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`HttpServletRequest.getParts()` returns a `Collection` which does not allow index based access as `Lists` do.

You could first copy all parts into an `ArrayList` and then loop over that list:

```
ArrayList<Parts> parts = new ArrayList<>(request.getParts());
for (int i=0; i<parts.size()-1; i+=2) {
    // parts.get(i);
    // parts.get(i+1);
}
```

Comment: Its right.. thanks for your response. i found another way by using list iterator too..

Comment: @Jambu: if it is right you may consider to accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is helping ...
I did it with an for each loop.
**Application example:**

```
for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
    // Your code. For example:
    fileName = getFileName(part);
    part.write(fileName);
}

private String getFileName(Part part) {
    String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    String[] tokens = contentDisp.split(";");
    for (String token : tokens) {
        if (token.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            return token.substring(token.indexOf("=") + 2, token.length() - 1);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

I hope it helped!